# Can`t log in to dekstop 119: export: 192.168.1.102: bad variable name

Tags: login, lightdm

I can't log in to desktop, password is correct, but when I log in then screen goes black and goes back to login screen.

With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I went to shell then logged in for to check `.Xsession-errors` then I saw that the problem is here:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 119: export: 192.168.1.102: bad variable name
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you please include the *full, verbatim* content of `~/.Xsession-errors` in your question? Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: That is all of `.xsession-errors`. only one line.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` has a problem

in line  119: which holds:

```
export: 192.168.1.102
```

You should fix that line.

Comment: But my  _/usr/sbin/lightdm-session_ only has 98 lines. It is puzzling.

Comment: @杨锦修 check your `~/.profile`.

Comment: @muru I have added  `. ~/Applications/onos/tools/dev/bash_profile` (onos bash_profile) to my .profile . I run `source .profile`. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: @杨锦修 Maybe in that particular instance there's nothing wrong. Doesn't mean that some `if` condition in it causes a different command to be run in some other instance.

Comment: @muru After I delete the line . It works fine. But I do not kown what is wrong.

Comment: @杨锦修 that's a problem for onos.

Comment: Possibly you have a space in an assignment such as `export CELL_WARDEN= "192.168.1.102"` in place of `export CELL_WARDEN="192.168.1.102"`